# How to debug nondeterministic memory corruption?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, memory-corruption

I have a nondeterministic memory corruption problem. Because it's not always the same address, and it occurs only rarely, I can't simply `watchpoint` it with `gdb`.

The problem is a value changes between point A and point B in my program. The only thing that is supposed to change it is point C, which does not run in that time (at least not for the specific instance that experiences the unexpected modification).

What I'd like to do is something like `mprotect` the value at point A so the machine will trap if it is modified and unprotected it again around the intentional modification at point C. Of course, `mprotect` is not meant to be taken literally as I need it to work with word granularity.

Simply watchpointing at point A manually with `gdb` is far too much toil, the frequency of the problem is only about one per thousand.

Ideally, I would like a stack trace at the point that modifies it.

Any ideas?

**Update:** I just found out about `rr` http://rr-project.org/, a tool that can allegedly "determinize" non-determinism problems. I'm going to give it a go.

**Update2:** Well that was a short trip:

```
[FATAL /build/rr-jR8ti5/rr-4.1.0/src/PerfCounters.cc:167:init_attributes() errno: 0 'Success'] 
 -> Microarchitecture `Intel Merom' currently unsupported.
```

Comment: Look up Asan and UBsan.

Comment: Remember that a breakpoint can have a set of gdb commands associated with it.  You could set a breakpoint on A that sets the write watch on the value and continues execution then have a break point on B that disables the watch.  Since value isn't supposed to change between A and B, this should help you catch if that does happen during that period of time.

Comment: @MichaelBurr That's an interesting approach - basically that's what I do now, but I decided to just script it with `Ruby` rather than learn how to script `gdb` (added an answer).

Comment: From personal experience, I found that using `lli` and clang from the LLVM suite would be helpful in investigating undefined behavior. I found that nondeterministic behavior would turn into undefined "highly reproducible chaos" that would help me troubleshoot the issue. Separate runs of `lli` on the same bitcode would create reproducible results.

Comment: @rlee827 There's a difference between undefined and nondeterministic. Undefined is e.g. making an unaligned memory access when the consequences of this are not specified by the language. But that's deterministic because, whatever happens, you expect it to happen the same way each time. Nondeterministic is e.g., polling a socket with a timeout - if a packet comes in close to the timeout, it could go either way and you can't consistently force it one way or the other. Yet the behavior is defined, because the spec says timing is not exact.

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing undefined behavior and it's being caused somewhere else, debugging this is really hard.

Since you are apparently on Linux, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and it will help you a lot. If you are not on Linux or (*OS X which is also supported by valgrind*), search for equivalent memory error detection software for your system.

Comment: I did think of valgrind but I'm not quite sure what valgrind would do in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

I found that it isn't that difficult to script `gdb` in a scripting language that you know (in my case, `Ruby`). This cuts down on the need to learn how to make proper `gdb` scripts!

The API between the target program and the script is that the target program has a blank function called `my_breakpoint` that accepts a single machine word as an argument. Calling `my_breakpoint(1); my_breakpoint(addr);` adds an address to the watch list while the same thing with the constant `2` removes an address  from the watch list.

To use this, you need to start `gdbserver 127.0.0.1:7117 myapp myargs`, and then launch the following script. When the script detects a problem, it disconnects cleanly from `gdbserver` so that you can reconnect another instance of `gdb` with `gdb -ex 'target remote 127.0.0.1:7117'` and off you go.

Note that it's *extremely* slow to use software watchpoints like this; maybe someday something like this can implemented as valgrind tool.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

system("rm -f /tmp/gdb_i /tmp/gdb_o");
system("mkfifo /tmp/gdb_i /tmp/gdb_o");
system("killall -w gdb");
system("gdb -ex 'target remote 127.0.0.1:7117' </tmp/gdb_i >/tmp/gdb_o &");

$fo = File.open("/tmp/gdb_i", "wb");
$fi = File.open("/tmp/gdb_o", "rb");

def gdb_put(l)
  $stderr.puts("gdb_out: #{l}");
  $fo.write((l + "\n"));
  $fo.flush;
end

gdb_put("b my_breakpoint");
gdb_put("set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0");
gdb_put("c");

$state = 0;
$watchpoint_ctr = 1; # start at 1 so the 1st watchpoint gets 2, etc. this is because the breakpoint gets 1.
$watchpoint_nr = {};

def gdb_got_my_breakpoint(x)
  $stderr.puts("my_breakpoint #{x}");

  if ((x == 1) || (x == 2))
    raise if ($state != 0);
    $state = x;
    gdb_put("c");
  else
    if ($state == 1)
      raise if ($watchpoint_nr[x].nil?.!);
      $watchpoint_nr[x] = ($watchpoint_ctr += 1);
      gdb_put("watch *#{x}");
    elsif ($state == 2)
      nr = $watchpoint_nr[x];
      if (nr.nil?)
        $stderr.puts("WARNING: ignoring delete request for watchpoint #{x} not previously established");
      else
        gdb_put("delete #{nr}");
        $watchpoint_nr.delete(x);
      end
    end
    $state = 0;
    gdb_put("info breakpoints");
    $stderr.puts("INFO: my current notion: #{$watchpoint_nr}");
    gdb_put("c");
  end
end

def gdb_got(l)
  t = l.split;

  if ((t[0] == "Breakpoint") && (t[2] == "my_breakpoint"))
    gdb_got_my_breakpoint(t[3][3..-2].to_i);
  end

  if (l.start_with?("Program received signal ") || l.start_with?("Watchpoint "))
    gdb_put("disconnect");
    gdb_put("q");
    sleep;
  end
end

while (l = $fi.gets)
  l = l.strip;

  $stderr.puts("gdb_inp: #{l}");

  gdb_got(l);
end
```

Comment: I'm just curious - did this help you find the problem already, or are you still working on it?  Also I don't think you need to learn "gdb scripting" to do something like this without ruby.  You can just associate a list of commands that gdb will run when the breakpoint is hit - the same commands you'd enter manually in gdb when the breakpoint stopped execution of the program is usually all you need.  See http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands

Comment: Also, why are you setting `can-use-hw-watchpoints` to 0?  If you're looking at a particular location of memory being changed, wouldn't using the hardware debug watchpoints capability speed things up considerably?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes it helped me find the problem, which is now fixed. At least on my system, hardware watchpoints have to be disabled because `gdb` does not gracefully revert to software watchpoints when you exceed the limit of hardware watchpoints.

Comment: Nice.  If I ever have to script GDB I hope I can remember this answer to refer to.